# Real mouse coordinate with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

How to get REAL mouse position coordinat always?
If I use mobile device and use horizontal scroll my X-coordinate is always start from left side of mobile browser...
Here is example
[JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EleGant/0fewydvv/)

```
document.getElementById('ass').onmousemove = function(e) {
var h = this.offsetWidth;
var prop = $("#ass").prop('naturalWidth')/h;
var x = prop*e.pageX  -$(window).scrollLeft();
var y = prop*e.pageY;
$("#coor").text(x+' - '+y);
}
```

As you can see on this image If I don't use scroll I get a real coordinates
[image]
But if I use scroll i get a NOT REAL coordinates.. I get a coordinate from border of window
[image]

Comment: try offset instead of pageX and pageY

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: my net is slow, so I cannot. research.